# How to SUM the value of a field and add in map values when I need to group by two fields/keys in map of map

Tags: soql

I need to show different table in VF as per Product_Category__c and sum of Volume__c for each Brand_Name__c

```
Below was my controller code please suggest how to populate sum of Volume__c in below map:

list<Rebate_Goal_Brand__c> rebBrand = new list<Rebate_Goal_Brand__c>([SELECT Brand_Name__c,Product_Category__c ,Name,Volume__c FROM Rebate_Goal_Brand__c where Contract__r.name =:contractId and Contract__r.Sales_Org__r.Sales_Org_Code__c='5191' and Product_Category__c != 'Outros']);
        
        for(Rebate_Goal_Brand__c rB: rebBrand)
        {
            if(!MapGoals.containsKey(rb.Product_Category__c) ){
                MapGoals.put(rb.Product_Category__c, new map<string,string>());
            }
            MapGoals.get(rb.Product_Category__c).put(rb.Brand_Name__c,string.valueOf(rb.Volume__c));
```

Comment: salesforce has a stack exchange you might get better responses on

Comment: Below is the code from Visualforce page
          <apex:repeat value="{!MapGoals}" var="keys1" id="theRepeat">
    <apex:outputText value="Product Category"/> 
      </th>
     <th>
    <apex:outputText value="Brand"/>
    <th >
   <apex:outputText value="SUM Volume (Kg/L)"/>
     <apex:repeat value="{!MapGoals[keys1]}" var="BN" 
 id="theRepeat">
  <tr>
   <td >
  <apex:outputText value="{!keys1}"/> 
 </td>
 <td>
 <apex:outputText value="{!BN}"/>
</td>
<td>
<apex:outputText value="{!MapGoals[keys1][BN]}"/>